# "Address already in use" when trying to start a tcpListener after stoping it

Tags: c#, ios, sockets, xamarin

I'm starting this tcpListener to any ip on port 3000, so after i close my popup that runs this method i call tcpListener.Stop().
After when i rty to reuse again i got this exeption "Adress already in use" so im thinking how can i clean that adress or something like that so i can start listening to it again?

```
tcpListener = new TcpListener (IPAddress.Any, 3000);
```

Here's the code.

I already tried to clean that door anyway i could think, but didn't worked, no method from that tcplistener cleans that.

Any ideia?

Comment: Do you have a client using that? The docs say "The `Stop` method does not close any accepted connections. You are responsible for closing these separately."

Comment: No accepted connections for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about your problem, but did you close the listener before you start to listen again?

I think the exception got raised because you want to listen on a reserverd port.
Try to close the listener before you start to listen again on the port 3000.

```
tcpListener.Close();
```

Greeds,
Lacky

Answer (score 4):

A good habbit to get into is the using keyword which will close the connection automatically when done. For Example:

```
using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
{
     //operations
     tcpClient.Close();
}
```

If you need to forcibly free up the socket you can set the SO_REUSEADDR socket option. You need to do this before binding to the listening port.

```
SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
```

Comment: Already read what is says and im closing everything i need to use this method but im not using socket itself im using tcpListener, any ideia how to do that on it?

Comment: The reuse of the address is very helpful. Thanks!