# UDP Address already in use Xamarin

Tags: ios, sockets, xamarin, xamarin.ios, udp

I'm trying to create a UDP server using `SocketLite.PLC` in Xamarin.

When running the iOS app I get the error `Address already in use` regardless of what port I try to listen to.

My code looks like this:

```
var udpReceived = new UdpSocketReceiver();
await udpReceived.StartListeningAsync(6932, allowMultipleBindToSamePort: false);
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I switched library. The one I was using was useless and buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
using (UdpSocketReceiver udpReceived = new UdpSocketReceiver())
{     
     //operations
     await udpReceived.StartListeningAsync(6932, allowMultipleBindToSamePort: false);
     udpReceived.Close();
}
```

I'm kind of betting on this being a similar issue to a thread I found regarding xamarin and the TcpListener ([which can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405367/adress-already-in-use-when-trying-to-start-a-tcplistener-after-stoping-it)).

Comment: Unfortunately, `Close()` does not exist, but `StopListening()` does. I still get the same error though. Can it be that I need to add something to `Entitlements.plist` to allow UDP connections to be used?